# Error when entering registration in backend

Tags: civievent

I have an problem, when registering participants manualy over the backend. If I choose an event having a pricelist, it shows the pricelist, but has two problems:

- It doesn't show the total sum of the fees!
- It doesn't show the form for editing the registration confirmation send by mail!

[image: uncomplete form]

In the browsers JS-Console, I get errors. This is, what I see in Chrome:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
(anonymous function) @ js_DMn29dQVNHfbgcdlcutXpB1hshlW6Su8HFMDl-TYa-A.js:2
m.extend.globalEval @ js_DMn29dQVNHfbgcdlcutXpB1hshlW6Su8HFMDl-TYa-A.js:2
m.fn.extend.domManip @ js_DMn29dQVNHfbgcdlcutXpB1hshlW6Su8HFMDl-TYa-A.js:4
m.fn.extend.append @ js_DMn29dQVNHfbgcdlcutXpB1hshlW6Su8HFMDl-TYa-A.js:4
(anonymous function) @ js_DMn29dQVNHfbgcdlcutXpB1hshlW6Su8HFMDl-TYa-A.js:4
m.access @ js_DMn29dQVNHfbgcdlcutXpB1hshlW6Su8HFMDl-TYa-    A.js:4
m.fn.extend.html @ js_DMn29dQVNHfbgcdlcutXpB1hshlW6Su8HFMDl-TYa-A.js:4
$.ajax.success @ add?reset=1&action=add&context=standalone:468
j @ js_DMn29dQVNHfbgcdlcutXpB1hshlW6Su8HFMDl-TYa-A.js:2
k.fireWith @ js_DMn29dQVNHfbgcdlcutXpB1hshlW6Su8HFMDl-TYa-A.js:2
x @ js_DMn29dQVNHfbgcdlcutXpB1hshlW6Su8HFMDl-TYa-A.js:5
b @ js_DMn29dQVNHfbgcdlcutXpB1hshlW6Su8HFMDl-TYa-A.js:5
```

Firefox tells me:

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
```

Sorry, I'm no use in this JS-things!

Bye

Answer (score 1):

I think, I found it!

I belive, it's a problem with the german translation! IMHO, it's because off the quotes in this code.

```
cj('form[name=Participant]').on("click", '.validate',
    function(e) {
      var userSubmittedStatus = cj('#status_id').val();
      var statusLabel = cj('#status_id option:selected').text();
      if (userModifiedAmount < feeAmount && userSubmittedStatus != partiallyPaidStatusId) {
        var msg = "Der gezahlte Betrag ist weniger als der erforderliche Betrag. Der erwartete Teilnehmerstatus ist "Teilweise bezahlt". Sind sie sicher den Teilnehmerstatus auf %1 zu setzen? Klicken Sie auf OK für weiter, Abbruch um die Daten zu ändern.";
        var result = confirm(ts(msg, {1: statusLabel}));
        if (result == false) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
  );
```

I belive, there should be no double quotes around "Teilweise bezahlt".

No I have to find the place, where this is defined!

Comment: Yes, that's it! after changing the double quotes to single quotes in po file and compiling it, it works fine!